# Error using koush websockects in android

Tags: android, node.js, websocket

I am trying to connect a node.js server with an android application, so I am using koush's websockets:

https://github.com/koush/android-websockets

thus, I have cloned the project and copied it to the android application's one and I could import the WebSockectClient without problems:

```
import com.codebutler.android_websockets.WebSocketClient;
```

Hence I guess that everything is ok but the problem is that in the example code is the next sentece:

```
WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient(URI.create("wss://irccloud.com"), new WebSocketClient.Handler() {...}
```

which makes eclipse raise error:

```
WebSocketClient.Handler cannot be resolved to a type
```

Looking the class WebSocketClient.java there is no Handler method... so I do not know what to do, what I am missing... if the example code is wrong or what but I guess that the problem is in my code.

Any advise?

EDIT:

I have noticed that WebSocketClient's generator ask for a Listener object instead of that Handler... but changing that is still not working and the code has another errors, I think I am going to try another implementation of websockects, which one would you recommend me? Gottox's?

EDIT 2:

I am now using Gottox's socket.io and everything is running perfectly

I let here the link to git in case someone wants it:

https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client

Comment: Is this a compile time error or a runtime one?

Comment: It is compile error, I cannot build the application due to this error.